# How do I prevent my RTL8821AE from dropping?

Tags: wireless

Each time I use Deja-Dup to backup to my NAS, my WiFi drops, and I have to restart network manager to get it to start again. I already installed the rtlwifi_new drivers from github, but they don't seem to make a difference. How can I prevent my WiFi from dropping when I upload large files? We’ll, it doesn’t show that the WiFi has disconnected, however all apps that require internet fail to load, and the system monitor shows nothing being uploaded or downloaded. 

 Note: I just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04, and the problem still exists.

The last 20 lines of(to save a lot of time on formatting)

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e wlan -e wlp
```

is:

```
Jun 15 11:47:36 nerdoflinux-X555LAB avahi-daemon[919]: Joining mDNS 
multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 10.42.0.66.
Jun 15 11:47:36 nerdoflinux-X555LAB avahi-daemon[919]: New relevant 
interface wlp3s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jun 15 11:47:36 nerdoflinux-X555LAB avahi-daemon[919]: Registering new 
address record for 10.42.0.66 on wlp3s0.IPv4.
Jun 15 11:47:36 nerdoflinux-X555LAB NetworkManager[951]: <info>  
[1497545256.6625] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check 
(reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Jun 15 11:47:36 nerdoflinux-X555LAB NetworkManager[951]: <info>  
[1497545256.6633] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-check -> 
secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Jun 15 11:47:36 nerdoflinux-X555LAB NetworkManager[951]: <info>  
[1497545256.6638] device (wlp3s0): state change: secondaries -> 
activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Jun 15 11:47:36 nerdoflinux-X555LAB NetworkManager[951]: <info>  
[1497545256.8947] policy: set 'Auto Linux is the Best(Secure)' 
(wlp3s0) as 
default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jun 15 11:47:37 nerdoflinux-X555LAB NetworkManager[951]: <info>  
[1497545257.2527] device (wlp3s0): Activation: successful, device 
activated.
Jun 15 11:47:37 nerdoflinux-X555LAB dnsmasq[1446]: using nameserver 
10.42.0.1#53(via wlp3s0)
Jun 15 11:47:37 nerdoflinux-X555LAB nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' 
[wlp3s0]: new request (2 scripts)
Jun 15 11:47:37 nerdoflinux-X555LAB nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' 
[wlp3s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Jun 15 11:47:37 nerdoflinux-X555LAB ntpd[1700]: Listen normally on 3 
wlp3s0 10.42.0.66:123
Jun 15 11:47:37 nerdoflinux-X555LAB ntpd[1700]: Listen normally on 5 
wlp3s0 [fe80::44ef:20ab:c5ef:3b2c%3]:123
Jun 15 11:47:43 nerdoflinux-X555LAB wpa_supplicant[1304]: wlp3s0: WPA: 
Group rekeying completed with 00:0f:60:05:20:00 [GTK=TKIP]
Jun 15 11:49:57 nerdoflinux-X555LAB kernel: [   22.087820] rtl8821ae: 
Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw_wowlan.bin
Jun 15 11:49:57 nerdoflinux-X555LAB kernel: [   22.242683] rtl8821ae 
0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
Jun 15 11:49:58 nerdoflinux-X555LAB kernel: [   28.003021] IPv6: 
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
Jun 15 11:49:58 nerdoflinux-X555LAB kernel: [   28.326028] IPv6: 
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
Jun 15 11:49:58 nerdoflinux-X555LAB kernel: [   28.593154] IPv6: 
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons that your wireless might be dropping. First, let's turn off power saving in Network Manager. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Next, there are a couple of driver parameters that control power saving. Let's apply them:

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r rtl8821ae
modprobe rtl8821ae ips=0 fwlps=0
exit
```

If this is helpful, make it persistent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8821ae ips=0 fwlps=0"  >  /etc/modprob.d/rtl8821ae.conf
exit
```

Finally, it is often the case that routers are set to have seperate 2.4 gHz and 5 gHz segments that are, by default, named the same. Many Linux drivers are troubled by roaming from one segment to the other and, of course, dropping in the switch-over. If this is your case, I recommend that you rename the segments to different names such as NerdofL24 and NerdofL5. Then experiment connecting to each to see which is most stable and fastest.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately even after following all the above steps, my WiFi works fine until I run a backup and it starts uploading.

Comment: Any clues in the log? `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e wlan -e wlp`

Comment: Please see: "wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 00:0f:60:05:20:00 [GTK=TKIP]"  Is your encryption really TKIP? I think you will have much better luck with AES, sometimes called CCMP. We see nothing in the log suggesting a drop. May we see the *last* 20 lines before a drop?

Comment: It is the last 20 lines, I made a typo. I put the output of the command into tail -n 20 right after my WiFi dropped.

Comment: Other than TKIP, I don't see anything else to suggest based on the log.

Comment: I don’t know how to change the cipher. I use an old Ubuntu laptop and a usb WiFi adapter for my hotspot.

Comment: I assume it's somewhere in the settings in the old laptop in Network Manager.  I've never set up a hotspot in Ubuntu before; sorry.

Answer (score 0):

That is a problem in Linux which is fixed for a time. Just use a newer release of Ubuntu like 17.04, or install a newer version of linux on your current release if you know what are you doing.

Answer (score 0):

#### Preconditions

In my case I have an Apple AirPort router with 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz networks turned on.  I verified that Apple router uses the same network name for both 2.4 and 5.

#### Solution

I disabled 2.4 GHz on my router and XFinity speed test went from 2 MB/s to 20 MB/s.  That was the solution for me.

#### Justification

I saw in the logs that connection was re-established roughly every 10 minutes and I saw a lot of rekeying of key.  Based on the logs I could tell that Linux was definitely mixing 2.4 and 5 GHz networks, because I could see different target Mac addresses.  Apple router Mac addresses are different for each frequency of the network name. I think this mixed use of target Mac addresses was confusing Linux and possibly the router.  I even observed other Wi-Fi devices got affected by temporary loss of Wi-Fi.

I am not sure if connection loss is fully resolved, but it is certainly a step in the right direction.

I was using the current up to date Linux Arch as of April 4, 2021.